# How to remove \ before quotes in a input form

Tags: php, html

Hi when I post something on my site and use quotations in it I get something like this

\"

What do I need to do to my code to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s probably [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) that’s causing this behavior. Try to [disable them or remove them](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) with [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes).

Comment: Thanks
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off 
in the .htaccess file did fix it!

Comment: You didn't think to google "php remove slashes"? It's the first link... it even mentions "magic quotes" in the PHP.net documentation. Everything is there at your fingertips...

Comment: Hi Mark, I enjoy using stackoverflow so I figure why not ask and continue to support SO.

Comment: No - don't use stripslashes except as a LAST resort.

Magic quotes are deprecated and have never worked properly. The right way to solve this is to remove the magic_quotes settings from the php.ini (and other places where these values can be set).

C.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the PHP setting magic_quotes_gpc which is a mess to work with. You can use stripslashes to take away the slashes, but then the code won't work if the magic_quotes_gpc setting is off. Something like this will probably solve it for you:

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['msg'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $string = stripslashes($string);
}
?>
```

Or remove them altogether (this will work both with and without magic_quotes_gpc, good for the times when you can't change the server configuration):

```
<?php
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  foreach(array('_POST', '_GET', '_COOKIE') as $gpc) {
    foreach($$gpc as $k => $v) {
      ${$gpc}[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Stripslashes() to get it to output without them. Default about it is here

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php