# Remove "\" in echo's and nl2br

Tags: php

So I have it when someone fills out a form the output gets put on a template which can be copy and pasted into a forum, here is the issue I have.

Here is part of the PHP code of putting it into the form (Just for example)

```
nl2br("\n[list][b]Unit #:[/b] ").$_POST["unit"].
nl2br("\n[b]Crew Members:[/b] ").$_POST['members'].
```

Now if the user puts a ' in the text here is what the output is;

```
[list][b]Unit #:[/b] Skent\'s Unit
[b]Crew Members:[/b] Can\'t
```

How do you remove it so \ is not placed before " ' " in the text thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php. You should look into your PHP configuration and see if you have magic quotes on; if so turn them off then you don't need to use this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove \ before quotes in a input form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004755/how-to-remove-before-quotes-in-a-input-form)